# Where are Object class extension GUIDs stored in Oracle?

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

Where are the GUIDs for object class and workspace extensions stored in SDE for Oracle? I've looked through GDB.ITEMS but can't seem to find it. I think SQL Server stores it in an .xml column but I don't see the equivalent in Oracle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for can be found in the SDE_XML_DOC# tables stored as ArcSDE XML (CLOB in Oracle in this case). Here's an example of the workflow for a feature class called "SDE.Test":

```
    SELECT NAME, DEFINITION, DOCUMENTATION FROM SDE.GDB_ITEMS WHERE NAME = 'SDE.Test';

    NAME        DEFINITION  DOCUMENTATION
    SDE.Test    61          11

SELECT XML_DOC_VAL FROM SDE.SDE_XML_DOC1 WHERE SDE_XML_ID=61;

--Contains the full XML Document with a searchable text index.

SELECT XML_DOC_VAL FROM SDE.SDE_XML_DOC2 WHERE SDE_XML_ID=11;

--Contains GP Tool history and Metadata with a searchable text index.
```

There's some more info here and a diagram, search for `SDE_XML_DOC<COLUMN_ID>`:

[XML columns in a geodatabase stored in Oracle](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002n00000071000000)

Answer (score 3):

In Oracle geodatabases, the DEFINITION column is an ArcSDE XML type rather than the native Oracle XML type which stores the information as BLOBs. To enable reading these values, the SDE schema in Oracle contains a view for the GDB_Items table named GDB_Items_vw

for details http://support.esri.com/ES/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38375